# c# - Deserialize JSON with index array

Tags: c#, json, serialization

In response I get JSON

```
{
  "message": "The request is invalid.",
  "modelState": {
    "users[0].FirstName": [
      "First name is required",
      "First name should contains at least one letter"
    ],
    "users[1].FirstName": [
      "First name is required",
      "First name should contains at least one letter"
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I deserialize with index ? 
I'm using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject and want to create POJO object for this response

Comment: Where did that JSON come from?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do that directly. You need to parse it in steps. If you control the source - fix the problem there.

Comment: parse the modelState into a string,string, and loop on that to select the item you want avoding this wrongly named property name. And creating an instance of the pojo class you want. Exactly the same way like if you wanted to handle a json where the important information is in the property name instead of beeing in the value. Or when you have a dynamic property name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choose Dictionary. It works, but it this solution your work with string, not POJO. But is possible to cast string to POJO

```
public class UserErrorMessage
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string[]> ModelState { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need mapping classes to deserialize your JSON. For the tricky key `users[0].FirstName` which looks like a property of other class you can use the `JsonProperty` attribute.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string jsonStr = "{\"message\": \"The request is invalid.\", \"modelState\": { \"users[0].FirstName\": [\"First name is required\", \"First name should contains at least one letter\" ],\"users[1].FirstName\": [\"First name is required\", \"First name should contains at least one letter\" ]}}";

    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(jsonStr);

    // Output
    Console.WriteLine("message: " + obj.message);
    Console.WriteLine("modelState:");
    Console.WriteLine("users[0].FirstName: ");
    foreach (var item in obj.modelState.Obj1)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    Console.WriteLine("users[1].FirstName: ");
    foreach (var item in obj.modelState.Obj2)
        Console.WriteLine(item);

    Console.Read();
}

class Message
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public ModelState modelState { get; set; }
}

class ModelState
{
    [JsonProperty("users[0].FirstName")]
    public string[] Obj1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("users[1].FirstName")]
    public string[] Obj2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Output:**

`message: The request is invalid.
modelState:
users[0].FirstName:
First name is required
First name should contains at least one letter`

`users[1].FirstName:
The first name is required
First name should contains at least one letter`

Comment: it's not a solution, cos it can be user count change dynamicly